# How do I add a Java class to a Xamarin VS2017 project

Tags: java, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have some AIDL files that rely on a Java class called TransBean.java. I've added both to my Xamarin project. The Java class is just added to the root (is that OK?), but I have set the Build Action to AndroidJavaSource.

When I build the solution, I'm getting a TransBean.cs class in the obj folder, but it's empty. It doesn't even have the class definition in it, just a namespace definition. As a result, the code generated from the AIDL files that rely on it, have compilation errors.

Do I need to do anything else to get the Java class to convert to C# and compile when I build the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Aidl defines the interface, you would need to write the C# Implementation yourself (if that Java file is an implementation, you can just port it to C#, otherwise you could package it into a "binding" library (via a jar/aar) with the aidl and then call the Java class/methods via C#)

Comment: Thanks ill give the binding library a try first and report back, cheers!

Comment: Seems to have worked. Created a jar in Netbeans and added the class to it. Then created a binding library project in VS, add my new jar as an InputJar and android.jar (from the android SDK, which my class needed) as a ReferenceJar. Built it and then added the resulting DLL as a reference to my Xamarin project and it now compiles. If you add as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted - thanks :)